# Handling auth in Chrome Extension MV3

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, auth0, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building my first ever Chrome browser extension and I am struggling to find the right solution for handling authentication. There is a requirement that the extension stay logged in as long as possible, to reduce the need for the user to log in often. This means we would need to use Refresh Tokens. I would very much like to handle all authentication on the background script but this is no longer persistent in MV3 nor does it have access to the DOM.

This being the case, I see these options:

- use [Auth0 React SDK](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login) on the content scripts - this means all my authentication logic will run in a somewhat less secure environment but the token will be handled by the library and I will be able to access it in all my content and popup scripts (if I need persistence across page refreshes, I would still need to use `localStorage`, I believe). But this means that the background script will not have access to the token and it will need one of the other scripts to retrieve it and send it through a message
- implement the [Authorization Code Flow with PKCE](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce#create-code-challenge) following the steps in [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce) on the background script - this will mean that all my auth logic is running in a more secure environment but I don't have a way of storing the token, other than using `chrome.storage`. It's also a bit tricky to silently retrieve the token (or check if user is still logged in) from the background script (it can be done using an injected iframe and the `web_message` response type or with `chrome.identity`but there are still issues with the `redirect_uri` which needs to be listed in the `Allowed Origin` config of the Auth0 app - so you can only easily do this on the pages of the extension).

I know that the recommended solution for an SPA is using the SDK but I would like to know if this is also the right solution for a browser extension. Based on this article on [Token Storage](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/security-guidance/data-security/token-storage), `localStorage` is dangerous especially due to third-party scripts. Seeing that the MV3 manifest has now removed the ability to execute remote code, is `localStorage` an acceptable way to store tokens?

I have implemented both options using the docs provided but I am unsure as to what is the best solution, given the changes introduced by MV3.

Thank you

Comment: If the persistence of the background script is your main concern/blocker, simply use chrome.storage.session.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for you reply. How would storage.session work with keeping the user logged in for a very long time? Isn't the idea of storage.session to keep data for the duration of a browser session?

Comment: My suggestion is only within the scope of the `if` condition i.e. if you were previously storing the token as a variable inside the background script.